# Asp.Net Core Unit Testing Delete Method in controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, asp.net-core, moq

I'm unit testing controller logic in a asp.net core project with xUnit and Moq, and I'm having trouble with testing the delete method. I have tried to put together some ideas from different tutorials etc. but still struggling.

I have managed to test that the method returns NoContentResult, and the NotFoundResponse. What I am missing here is the test to see that the delete method actually has deleted an item from the Bygg Repository.

What I am trying to do here in this case is to retreive the list of Bygg, delete an item, and then use assert to check if the list now only contains 2 items.

fyi: bygg = building.

The project follows a repository pattern with generic and userspecific repositories.

This is the delete method in the controller:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteBygg(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var bygg = await _byggRepository.GetByggByIdAsync(id);
        if (bygg == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        await _byggRepository.DeleteByggAsync(bygg);

        return NoContent();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

This is the test method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task DeleteBygg_ExistingIdPassed_RemovesOneItem()
{
    // Arrange
    _mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.DeleteByggAsync(It.IsAny<Bygg>()));
    _mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetAllByggAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(GetTestBygg());

    // Act
    var actual = await _controller.GetAllBygg();
    var actual2 = actual as OkObjectResult;
    var noContentResponse = await _controller.DeleteBygg(1);


    // Assert
    var items = Assert.IsType<List<Bygg>>(actual2.Value);
    Assert.Equal(2, items.Count);
}
```

Comment: You could just try verifying that the mocks receive the expected calls when the test is exercised. No need to get all and check items

Comment: You mocked `DeleteByggAsync` method so it won't actually delete anything. Maybe that is wrong scenario to test. You could maybe just verify if `DeleteByggAsync` has been called with the expected argument. The place to test actual delete is while unit testing `byggRepository`...

Comment: It also looks like you are trying to test too many things in one unit test.

Comment: To expand on what NKosi said, You need to keep your tests simple. In this case you dont actually care that something is deleted because your DeleteByggAsync tests should verify that. All you care about for your controller is that the call is delegated properly. While writing tests always think about what can be removed/simplified

Comment: For info, this is not unit test. This is integration test. You are in a web context (controller) and you are testing EF and Database interation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not returning anything from the `DeleteBygg` method, you need to just verify in the test method that `await _byggRepository.DeleteByggAsync(bygg);` is calling correctly in your actual method as follows:

```
[Fact]
public async Task DeleteBygg_ExistingIdPassed_RemovesOneItem()
{        
    // Arrange
    var id = 1;
    _mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetByggByIdAsync(id)).ReturnsAsync(new Bygg(){});
    _mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.DeleteByggAsync(It.IsAny<Bygg>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

    // Act
    await _controller.DeleteBygg(id);

    // Assert
    _mockRepo.Verify(repo => repo.DeleteByggAsync(It.IsAny<Bygg>()),Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: I think I have got a better idea of how to unit test the controller now. So if I've managed to figure this out, when testing controller logic, we are testing that the calls are executing correctly. In many of the other tests for the controller I have used Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(input) for example to check that the correct objectresponse has been returned. As well as checking that data is returned where it is applicable. 

Further, I probably will have to unit test the repositories as well?? Or is it enough to test only the controller only? Sounds like a retorical question haha!

Comment: Yes! You have to write test method for repository methods too. Thanks